# Two equal PHP statements giving different results?

Tags: php

I was doing some coding on my phone when I got this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"log.txt"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in your code on line 15
```

This is the offending code:

```
 $file = "log.txt";
```

Note that you have to copy this exactly to get this result. This is because when I retype it:

```
$file = "log.txt";
```

I get no error. The two lines are the same, except for one thing: the second space in the line is binary "10100000" in the crashing statement, but "00100000" in the retyped one.

So I suppose my editor screwed up in some mystical way I will probably never discover. But what I don't get is why does this bad character look exactly like a space (as opposed to something else or a �), and why does it cause this particular error as if I didn't properly open my string?

Comment: You've probably seen `&nbsp;` before.  It stands for non-breaking space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space) character.

It probably came about as a result of copying the code in from a blog post or from Word, for example.

The interpreter is not able to parse it as a regular space, hence the error.

Comment: That seems to be it. Thanks!